# Call an element in a tuple in a list and keep getting an unsubscriptable type error

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples, element

Python 2

This is what is happening

```
>>> highscores= [('A',7),('B',8),('C',3),('D',2)]
>>> highscores[0][1]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    highscores[0][1]
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

I'm super new at programming and I just don't why this is happening

Comment: I get `>>> highscores[0][1]` => `7`, is there other context before that assignment?

Answer (score 0):

What is pyshell, and why are you using it? It seems to be doing something very funky to your interpreter!

Checkout your code on codepad.org, it works just fine: http://codepad.org/HOXTWKC5

IMHO, When just starting out, don't use any "helpers", like pyshell, eclipse, iPython, etc. They'll just get in your way more often than you realize. Of course, YMMV.